# Redis throw exceptioon about "Read time out"

Tags: java, multithreading, redis

I'm the new to redis, I start the server about this [tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart). And it work. Then I use write the code using java to connect redis, then it's ok, like this:

```
      Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
      System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
      //store data in redis list
      jedis.lpush("tutorial-list", "Redis");
      jedis.lpush("tutorial-list", "Mongodb");
      jedis.lpush("tutorial-list", "Mysql");
```

But, when I use multithread to push the redis, it will throw the exception "read time out":

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:201)
>     at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
>     at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:141)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:233)
>     at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.keys(Jedis.java:185)   at
>   org.v11.redis_mongo_task.UpdateApp.jobDetail(UpdateApp.java:23)   at
>   org.v11.redis_mongo_task.UpdateApp.main(UpdateApp.java:42)    ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:107)   at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:195)
>     ... 13 more

What happened for redis? why it can work in single thread?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107383/why-a-single-jedis-instance-is-not-threadsafe), a single Jedis instance is not threadsafe. You will have to use JedisPool for multithreading. You can read [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started) on how use it and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230503/how-jedis-pool-works) to set the max connections and what will happen if those connections are all occupied.

I'm posting links since two of them are SO answers an they should get the credit and one is from github official repo, so if anything gets updated it should be reflected here too.